# Issue with the background and z-index

Tags: html, css

Here's the code that works the right way only if you remove **background: #a1a1a1;** from the *.sign-up form*. But I need the background. Changing **z-index** doesn't help since -1 value is too small and 0 is to big.
How to fix this problem?
Thank You.

```css
.sign-up__form {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 5px solid #ff4e50;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.register-switch {
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.register-switch-input {
  display: none;
}
.register-switch-label {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.register-switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label:after {
  background: tomato;
}
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<form name="sign-up" class="sign-up__form">
  <div class="register-switch">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex-m" class="register-switch-input" checked>
    <label for="sex-m" class="register-switch-label">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex-f" class="register-switch-input">
    <label for="sex-f" class="register-switch-label">Female</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `z-index` on the `.sign-up__form` rule as well ..

```css
.sign-up__form {
  width: 260px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 5px solid #ff4e50;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.register-switch {
  height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.register-switch-input {
  display: none;
}
.register-switch-label {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.register-switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label:after {
  background: tomato;
}
.register-switch-input:checked + .register-switch-label {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<form name="sign-up" class="sign-up__form">
  <div class="register-switch">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex-m" class="register-switch-input" checked>
    <label for="sex-m" class="register-switch-label">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex-f" class="register-switch-input">
    <label for="sex-f" class="register-switch-label">Female</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome .. and I dropped 2:nd one to keep things simple

Comment: Thank you. That's perfect :)
But there's an issue with the rounded corners. If you set border-radius: 5px; - than you can see the stroke of the tomato background.
I did this:
 label[for="sex-m"]:after{
visibility: hidden;
  }
... and it seems to solve the issue. 
Is it correct?

Comment: Its not the "tomato background" that shows, it is the _.sign-up__form_ rules `border-top: 5px solid #ff4e50;` ... delete that border-top and you'll see it goes away

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, which element do you mean to set to `border-radius: 5px;` that cause you to see the "tomato background"?

Comment: Set it to .register-switch-label:after

Comment: I just did, even updated my answer, but can't see any tomato stroke. Which browser/version do you use? ... Btw, did you add more to the _.register-switch-label:after_ ?

Comment: Actually, you have to zoom in to see it. But thanks anyway. http://imgur.com/4vMoTU4